# How to disable application update options in intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to deploy a Spring application with Intellij. While I was working with the server and using [image: refresh icon] button, I did marked the "do not show this again" option as checked and instead of choosing redeploy, the "restart server" option was checked. I did read [Intellij's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/updating-applications-on-application-servers.html#update_options) but I did not find anything. I did add a new server, but apparently the previous setting is valid for the new server as well. Please advise.

Comment: Which application server do you use for your deployment?

Comment: I am using tomcat 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you clicked on 'Don't ask again' here:

[image]

If you wish for that dialog to appear again, then edit your Run Configuration and check 'Show Dialog':

[image]

after which on clicking 'Refresh' as in the first snapshot the dialog should appear again.

Furthermore, note that clicking on 'Don't ask again' will only affect the configuration of the specific Run Configuration. For instance, in the snapshots above, the only Run Configuration affected is `RunOnTomcat`.

The default configuration can be changed and will then affect all future Run Configurations. For instance, if you wished to not have the dialog appear for any future Tomcat Server Run configurations then you would uncheck the 'Show Dialog' option here:

[image]